# Define Dominating Set.

Tags: real-analysis, graph-theory, algorithms, definition

In Graph Theory there are some problems such as "The Independent Set Problem", "Vertex Cover" and "Dominating Set". The ideas of the first two are pretty simple:

1. "The Independent Set Problem" deals with given a number of connected nodes, color in the nodes in such a way that no connected nodes have the same colors.
2. "Vertex Cover" deals with the fact that you're also given a certain amount of connected nodes, find the minimum amount of nodes that encompass all the connections.

My problem is with the "Dominating Set" because I can't find any good articles or videos that explain this properly.

Comment: Why are you not happy with the first line in Wikipedia's definition and picture? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313919/proof-that-dominating-set-is-np-complete) is a clear statement of the **problem** (the statement might be clear if you are already familiar with the vertex cover problem):

> Dominating Set: input undirected $G$, integer $k > 0$. Is there a subset of vertices $S$, $|S|\leq k$, that dominates all vertices?

A very clear (at least to me) **definition** of a dominating set is found [here](https://www.nitt.edu/home/academics/departments/cse/faculty/kvi/NPC%20DOMINATING%20SET.pdf):

> A dominating set in a graph $G$ is a subset
>   of vertices $S \subseteq V$ such that each vertex in $V$ is either in $S$ or is adjacent to some vertex in $S$.